# One Question about BlipForConditionalGeneration

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I create a Blip model by:
`BlipModel = BlipForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")`

I want to get the hidden state of the model output. I got this problem:

I just used the `BlipModel(pixel_values = ipt)` for the inference part. I create a dummy input by `ipt = torch.randn((1,3,384,384))`. When the input batch size is 1, everything works fine.
However, when I tried to change the input's batch size to another number, like 2, `ipt = torch.randn((2,3,384,384))`. Then I got this kind of error:

**ValueError: Expected input batch_size (2) to match target batch_size (1).**

[image: error info image]

I don't know how to fix this one